# Trying to float divs in unordered list

Tags: html, css, list, css-float, html-lists

I'm a budding web designer and do not always struggle with realizing my design into code, but today as I am working on a site, I have run into a problem.  I am trying to nest two divs within a `<li>` list element.  I would like one to span the full-height of the `<li>` element and `float: left;` while the other div contains two lines of text and I would like it to `float: right;`.  I think what I'm trying to do is fairly simple, but for some reason I'm just really struggling with getting this to work properly.  I'm essentially just making a list of calendar events, which eventually I'll use PHP to pull in data from a Google Calendar and re-populate the sample info you see below.

I'm trying to get the list to look like this:

[image: list design example]

Please keep in mind that to get the code working, I've replaced my Google Webfont for the time being in the CSS with just *Arial Black* and *Arial*. *Arial Black* should be used for the `.day` class font and *Arial* should be used for the `.info` class font (aka. the time and place lines).

### Any help would much be appreciated! Thanks!!

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="gcal">
    <li>
        <div class="gcal-event">
            <div class="day">
                6.07
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="time">8pm-10:30pm</span><br />
                    456 Fake Ln. Blvd., New York, NY
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="gcal-event">
            <div class="day">
                7.12
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="time">6pm-7pm</span><br />
                    123 Fake Ln., Chicago, IL
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.gcal {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

ul.gcal li {
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
    display: block;
}

.gcal-event {
}

.day {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 0.6em;
}

.info {
    float: right;
    width: 640px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.info span.time {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `li`s are losing their height. Floating children do not contribute to the height of the parent. Add `overflow: hidden` to the `li`s in order to solve this.

```
ul.gcal li {
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVX6U/)

Comment: thanks Ryan!  This works great using the most minimal amount of code possible.  Took kristina's advice above and also added a width property so that the floated content won't continue to scroll off the page.

Answer (score 2):

Floating elements within an element that is not floated causes problems. I find it helps to add background colors or borders to my code when trying to figure out what's happening. If you add a background color to all your elements you'll see that the `<li>` is missing. In order to help your browser determine where the containing element is you need to group it with the floats. You've got a couple options, either

```
ul.gcal li {
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

or adding a clear to the bottom of the floated content, like so

```
<li>
    <div class="gcal-event">
        <div class="day">
            7.12
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <span class="time">6pm-7pm</span><br />
                123 Fake Ln., Chicago, IL
        </div>
    </div>
    <br clear="all">
</li>
```

The `clear="all"` property isn't encouraged anymore (instead, we are supposed to use a clear class on the next element `.clear { clear:both; }`) but I still do sometimes. I mean... no I don't! !ho said I did?? Slander!

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WkBgg/

the other thing I noticed is the `float:right;` with the hard-coded width. Depending on the size of the browser (like mobile browsers) this will cause some strange alignments with the content above it. You may want to re-think how you align those two. In the fiddle, if you shrink the window smaller than 640px you'll see what I mean.

Comment: The answer from @ryankinal is better. I had no idea you could do that. I don't really understand how it works, but it's a cool trick. What's browser support like on that?

Comment: ooh, found out why. it's here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html it looks like in addition to the `overflow:auto` you will also need to declare a width to make it compatible across all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try somethig like that: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vnp9T/1/). May be my example helps you. If you need something more ask me.